# Prolog: simple lexer/2

Tags: prolog, dcg

I need a small `lexer/2` in prolog, currently I have

```
tokens(Z) --> "while", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttwhile | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "do", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttdo | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "endwhile", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttendwhile | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "repeat", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttrepeat | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "until", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttuntil | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "endrepeat", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttendrepeat | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "if", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttif | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "then", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttthen | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "else", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttelse | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "endif", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttendif | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "exit", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttexit | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "other", tokens(Y), {Z = [ttother | Y]}.

% Comparison operators.
tokens(Z) --> "==", tokens(Y), {Z = [equal | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> "<>", tokens(Y), {Z = [notequal | Y]}.

% Assignment operator.
tokens(Z) --> ":=", tokens(Y), {Z = [:= | Y]}.  

% Boolean constants and operators.
tokens(Z) --> "true", tokens(Y), {Z = [true | Y]}.  
tokens(Z) --> "false", tokens(Y), {Z = [false | Y]}.  
tokens(Z) --> "and", tokens(Y), {Z = [and | Y]}.  
tokens(Z) --> "or", tokens(Y), {Z = [or | Y]}.  

tokens(Z) --> " ", tokens(Y), {Z = Y}.
tokens(Z) --> " ", tokens(Y), {Z = Y}.

tokens(Z) --> [C], tokens(Y), {name(X, [C]), Z = [X | Y]}.
tokens(Z) --> [], {Z = []}.
```

Can anyone help me with the next step for `lexer/2` so that when I call
`lexer([while,a,==,b,do,abc,endwhile], R)`, I could get `R = [ttwhile, a, equal, b, ttdo, abc, ttendwhile]`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that a double-quoted string is a shorthand for a list of character codes, i.e. `"abc" == [0'a, 0'b, 0'c]`.  Try `phrase(tokens(Ts), "while a==b do abc endwhile")`. But then try `phrase(tokens(Ts), "while bothered do")` and you'll see that you need to do something about delimiters.

Comment: You can avoid `{name(X, [C])}`, if you `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars)`, then`"abc" = [a,b,c]`

Comment: Thanks all for your help!

Comment: why dont you use `;` alternative instead of writing every posible token in new line, and check `phrase` predicate  `phrase(lexer(Output),Input)` read also about `read_lines_to_codes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, this 'glue' - more or less - solves your request:

```
lexer(L, Tokens) :-
    atomic_list_concat(L, ' ', A),
    atom_codes(A, Cs),
    phrase(tokens(Tokens), Cs).

?- lexer([while,a,==,b,do,abc,endwhile], R).
R = [ttwhile, a, equal, b, ttdo, a, b, c, ttendwhile] ;
R = [ttwhile, a, equal, b, ttdo, a, b, c, e|...] ;
```

but you should really rewrite in declarative style:

```
token(ttwhile) --> "while".
token(ttendwhile) --> "endwhile".
token(ttdo) --> "do".
%...
token(equal) --> "==".
token(notequal) --> "<>".
token(assign) --> ":=". 

% this is wrong: symbols overlap with alphabetic tokens
token(N) --> [C], {atom_codes(N,[C])}.

tokens([]) --> [].
tokens(Ts) --> " ", tokens(Ts).
tokens([T|Ts]) --> token(T), tokens(Ts).

lexer(Cs, Tokens) :-
    phrase(tokens(Tokens), Cs).
```

and call passing a codes list, a double quoted (or backquoted, if you're using SWI) string

```
?- lexer(`while abc endwhile`, R).
R = [ttwhile, a, b, c, ttendwhile] ;
R = [ttwhile, a, b, c, e, n, d, ttwhile] ;
...
```

*edit*

to tokenize names (well, only lowercase, for simplicity), replace the above `token(N) --> [C], {atom_codes(N,[C])}.` with

```
token(N) --> lower_case_chars(Cs), {Cs \= [], atom_codes(N,Cs)}.

lower_case_chars([C|Cs]) --> lower_case_char(C), lower_case_chars(Cs).
lower_case_chars([]) --> [].

lower_case_char(C) --> [C], {C>=0'a, C=<0'z}.
```

but it becomes a little verbose, when you add also upper_case_chars, digits, etc... it's worth to generalize, passing the characters range boundary, or use [code_type](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=char_type/2)/2:

```
token(N) --> csymf(C), csyms(Cs), {atom_codes(N,[C|Cs])}.

csymf(C) --> [C], {code_type(C,csymf)}.

csyms([C|Cs]) --> [C], {code_type(C,csym)}, csyms(Cs).
csyms([]) --> [].
```

Comment: Dear @CapelliC, thanks for your help, what about if I would like to keep abc  rather than a, b, c. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear @CapelliC, with some cases I got the error: ERROR: atomic_list_concat/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated. Can you help me solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: ok, but you should provide all details. It's better done posting another question though

Comment: Dear @CapelliC, tokenizefile('test.txt', L). I got L = [int, add, =, a, +, b]. When I call lexer([int, add, =, a, +, b], K). it is ok I got K = ['TYPE_INT', a, d, d, 'ASSIGN', a, 'ARITH_ADD', b], but when I run lexer(L,K). it throw that error. Thanks.

Comment: Means that L =  [int, add, =, a, +, b]. When I call lexer([int, add, =, a, +, b], K), it is ok but when I call lexer(L, K), it throw that error. Thanks.

Comment: The error is expected. lexer/2 requires the first argument instantiated. It's possible to overcome some of these problems, but it becomes pretty complex soon. So seems to be out of scope for this answer. You can try to call `?- lexer($L,K).` on the command line...

Comment: Dear @CapelliC, Means that L = [int, add, =, a, +, b]. When I call lexer([int, add, =, a, +, b], K), it is ok but when I call lexer(L, K), it throw that error. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @CapelliC, In this case, the first parameter of lexer is taking from the second result of tokenizefile('test.txt', L), means L. so can I call lexer(L, Result)? or what should I call? Thanks.

Comment: ah I understand now, it should be lexer($L, Result). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following solution?

```
lexer(I, O) :-
  tokens(O, I, []).
```

But calling `lexer()` in this way

```
lexer("while a == b do abc endwhile", R)
```

I add a suggestion: rewrite `tokens()` in this way

```
tokens([ttwhile | Z])     --> "while", tokens(Z).
tokens([ttdo | Z])        --> "do", tokens(Z).
tokens([endwhile | Z])    --> "endwhile", tokens(Z).
tokens([ttrepeat | Z])    --> "repeat", tokens(Z).
tokens([ttuntil | Z])     --> "until", tokens(Z).
tokens([ttendrepeat | Z]) --> "endrepeat", tokens(Z).
tokens([if | Z])          --> "if", tokens(Z).
tokens([then |Z])         --> "then", tokens(Z).
tokens([ttelse | Z])      --> "else", tokens(Z).
tokens([ttendif | Z])     --> "endif", tokens(Z).
tokens([ttexit | Z])      --> "exit", tokens(Z).
tokens([ttother | Z])     --> "other", tokens(Z).

% Comparison operators.
tokens([equal | Z])    --> "==", tokens(Z).
tokens([notequal | Z]) --> "<>", tokens(Z).

% Assignment operator.
tokens([:= | Z]) --> ":=", tokens(Z).  

% Boolean constants and operators.
tokens([true | Z])  --> "true", tokens(Z).  
tokens([false | Z]) --> "false", tokens(Z).  
tokens([and | Z])   --> "and", tokens(Z).  
tokens([or | Z])    --> "or", tokens(Z).  

tokens(Z) --> " ", tokens(Z).

tokens([X | Z]) --> [C], tokens(Z), {name(X, [C])}.
tokens([])      --> [].
```

P.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Dear @max66, thanks for your help, I will try to rewrite as you suggested.

Comment: `lexer/2` should rather read: `lexer(I, O) :-
  phrase(tokens(O), I).`  In this manner you are better maintaining the interface  between DCG-rules and regular Prolog goals.